# Learning node.js - recursive file search using event emitter pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I'm working through the exercises in [Node.js Design Patterns](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Node.js-Design-Patterns-Third-Edition). The exercise in chapter 4 asks you to use the event emitter pattern to recursively search all files in a directory, print the file names and add the content to an output file.

To capture the file names, I have created an array, then within a forEach loop I test for a match and if true push the file name into the array. The problem is that the final console.log statement seems to execute before the forEach loop runs so the output shows as empty

```
readFiles: All matching files:  []
```

Here is the function

```
function readFiles(srcDir, fileList, dstDir, destFile, keyword, queue, cb) {

  console.log("readFiles: Processing files:", fileList)
  const outputFile = path.join(dstDir, destFile)
  const matchingFiles = []

  fileList.forEach((file) => {
    fs.readFile((path.join(srcDir, file)), 'utf8', (err, fileContent) => {
        if (err) {
            if (err.code !== 'ENOENT') {
                return cb(err);
            }
        }

        if (fileContent.includes(keyword)) {
            console.log("readFiles: File Names: " + file);
            matchingFiles.push(file);
            console.log('readFiles: Matching File Content:', fileContent);
            saveFile(fileContent, dstDir, destFile, cb);
            if (err) {
                return cb(err);
            }
        }
    });
  });

  console.log("readFiles: All matching files: ", matchingFiles)
  return cb()
}
```

Its called from another function using

```
readFiles(srcDir, txtFiles, dstDir, destFile, keyword, queue, cb);
```

I don't think I'm properly understanding the async nature of the code execution within the function. Could someone explain why this is not working and what changes I need to make to correctly capture the matching files.

Thanks, Adam

Comment: Can you use `async`  `await` in your exercise? Anyway, there are no `emit` instructions here

Comment: It's kind of hard to offer help with a recursive question when you don't show the actual declaration of the function in question to see its arguments and see where the recursion occurs.

Comment: You are correct that you don't understand how non-blocking, asynchronous functions like `fs.readFile()` work.  The do NOT block and wait until completion.  They start executing and immediately return and your code after that statement then continues to execute.  Some time later, they will call their completion callback.  This would be 100 times easier if you can use `async/await` and `await fs.promises.readFile()`

Comment: The exercise is to learn how the event emitter works using a basic task queue rather than the async/wait libraries. I've updated the question to show the whole function and the call from the previous function

Comment: I was working on a suggested rewrite, but don't understand what `saveFile()` is and why it gets passed the callback and what you need for both error handling and handling any asynchronous part of `saveFile()`.  Can you include that code too?

Comment: SaveFile is another function that writes the output of the search to a file. You can ignore that as I'm really trying to understand the execution flow within the function so I can write out the filenames containing the keyword. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to understand here is that `fs.readFile()` is both asynchronous and non-blocking.  That means that as soon as it is called, it starts its operation and then returns (long before its complete).  This means that the rest of your code keeps executing while `fs.readFile()` is doing its thing.  Then, sometime later, `fs.readFile()` will call its callback to indicate completion or error.

But, because it doesn't "wait" to finish before returning, that should explain to you why the final `console.log()` statement executes before the `fs.readFile()` operations have completed.  Nodejs runs your entire `.forEach()` loop, starting all the `fs.readFile()` operations and then the loop is done and it executes your final `console.log()` statement, even though none of the `fs.readFile()` operations have yet called their completion callback.

In the modern world of Javascript, it is a ton easier to serialize multiple asynchronous operations by using `async` and `await`.  But, you've suggested that you aren't allowed to do that in this case.  So, my preferred implementation is essentially a simple state machine where in this case, the only state is the index of the `fileList` that you are iterating.  You can't use normal looping constructs like `.forEach()` or `for` because they won't wait for your asynchronous operations to complete before moving to the next iteration.  So, you create a manual iteration with a statemachine that manually calls the next iteration only when the previous iteration has completed.

Here's the general concept:

```
function readFiles(srcDir, fileList, dstDir, destFile, keyword, queue, cb) {

    console.log("readFiles: Processing files:", fileList);
    const outputFile = path.join(dstDir, destFile);
    const matchingFiles = [];

    let fileIndex = 0;

    function processNextFile() {
        // if there are no more files to process, then call the callback
        // with the matchingFiles as the completion value
        if (fileIndex >= fileList.length) {
            console.log("readFiles: All matching files: ", matchingFiles)
            cb(null, matchingFiles);
            return;
        }
        // get next input filename
        const file = fileList[fileIndex++];

        fs.readFile((path.join(srcDir, file)), 'utf8', (err, fileContent) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                if (err.code !== 'ENOENT') {
                    // this will stop all further processing, but
                    // only if the error is something other than ENOENT
                    // ENOENT errors will just skip that file
                    return cb(err);
                }
            } else {
                if (fileContent.includes(keyword)) {
                    console.log("readFiles: File Names: " + file);
                    matchingFiles.push(file);
                    console.log('readFiles: Matching File Content:', fileContent);
                    //saveFile(fileContent, dstDir, destFile, cb);
                }
            }
            // done processing this file, so start processing the next one
            processNextFile();
        });
    }
    // start processing the first file
    processNextFile();
}
```

I've commented out the call to `saveFile()` because it is likely also asynchronous and since you've not included its code or explained how errors in it should be handled with the callback, I can't properly integrate it into this.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you. I hadn't appreciated that a library call from within an asynchronous function would also be asynchronous, although sounds obvious now.  Or that you can nest functions within functions. So, in this case you call the function multiple times and use an index to iterate through all the files in the list.